# I have a reversable in O(1) double linked list, how do I join 2 of them?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I was asked to create a data base that can remove/insert/initialized values in O(1), so went for a linked list.
Later I needed to make it **reversable** in O(1). So I made it a double-linked list, and added a bool flag to tell the iterator what direction to go in. For example if the method `next()` was used, and the list is reversed, the flag is true, so next will actually go to the prev node.
The problem starts when I'm needed to join two of these lists, in O(1) too (everything need to be O(1)).
I can't find a way to join them if one is revered and the other is not!

My first attempt was the naive one. For example if I had lists 1,2,3 and 4,5,6, now I reverse 1,2,3 by changing the flag to true.
So the user will have 3,2,1 and 4,5,6 while the lists are really 1,2,3 and 4,5,6.
Now the user wants to join the two. S/he wants 3,2,1,4,5,6.
If I connect this way:
1,2,3->4,5,6
4's prev is 3, so you can't go run through the list. The user expects to start on 3. go to 2. go to 1. then go to 4. but 4 isn't there!
So I connect this way:
3,2,1->4,5,6
(connect 1 to 4)

If 4's prev is 1, 4 needs to be 1's next! But 2 is.
If I make 4 to be 1's prev and not next, then 4 is 1's prev, 1 is 4's prev, and running across the list will cause infinite loop. Doing prev,prev,perv will go back and forth between 1 and 4.
I have no way to connect them, so they can act as a one linked list, by the order each of them was, including the reversing.

Comment: The list isn't reversible. The *iterator* is reversible. You can create your own iterator which first traverses the first list forward, then the second list backward. Of course, this doesn't actually reverse or connect the lists. Rather, you just have an iterator that iterates them in the desired order. But then again, that's all your "reversible" lists supported too. They weren't actually reversing. They just had iterators that iterated in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

> was asked to create

Who asked? If it was work or school, if it involves some scripting language or some high level, garbage-collected language like java, then tell them it can't be done.

If it is some kind of hackers' contest where anything goes, and it involves some low level language like C++, then read on!

There is a little-known infamous way of creating a doubly linked list which involves a single pointer per node. It is ***extremely hacky***, so I would recommend extreme caution before using it for anything serious. It is not particularly portable, though it can be made to reliably work on the most commonly used architectures today.

It is called the ***XORed Doubly-Linked List***. You can read about it in many places, for example here: [everything2 - Storing a doubly-linked list using just a single pointer field](https://everything2.com/title/Storing+a+doubly-linked+list+using+just+a+single+pointer+field)

In brief, the trick is to combine the "prev" and "next" pointers into a single word, by bitwise-XORing them together. Let's call this the "prevXorNext" pointer, although it is not really a pointer, because you have to XOR it with "prev" to get "next", or XOR it with "next" to get "prev".

The idea is that when you look at a node, you have arrived at it from another node, so the address of the other node represents some information that you already have, and that information can be useful. Specifically, when you are looking at a node, you already have the address of either the "prev" or the "next" node, so you have what you need to XOR with the "prevXorNext" pointer to get the other "next" or "prev" pointer.

Since a XOR Doubly Linked List has only one pointer per node, all functions that operate on it work equally well regardless of whether you are traversing it in the forward direction or in the reverse direction. If you start at the head, you are traversing forward; if you start at the tail, you are traversing backward.

Thus, it should be fairly straightforward to join two such lists either front-to-back or back-to-front. The ***actual*** code that achieves this is left as an exercise to the reader.

**UPDATE**

After a brief discussion in the comments, user rcgldr implemented such a list in C++, see his answer.

Comment: I made a XOR list class in C++, with an O(1) reverse, and a O(1) join implemented as a splice (the other list can be inserted anywhere). I also implemented a recursive bottom up merge sort, similar to Visual Studio 2022's std::list. This merge sort involves working with 3 iterators per level of recursion, and I had to modify the logic to update both the previous as well as the current node pointers in the iterators as nodes get rearranged within the existing list via a splice(left, right) (move right node to just before left node).

Comment: @rcgldr that's quite awesome. If you post it on github/gitlab/etc please share a link.

Comment: Just added it. There are two main programs, using #if to switch which one to compile. The first one is a sort, the second one tests some of the basic functions. Needs some comments and some more functions, like push_front, peek_front, pop_front. https://github.com/jeffareid/misc/blob/master/xorlist.cpp

Comment: Clean up (like removing unneeded this-> references) and added some functions (push_back, peek_... pop_....) to xorlist.cpp. Link is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I was aware of xor linked lists, but never thought about implementing one until Mike Naki's answer explained it would be a solution to the question, so I initially wrote proof of concept code, and later cleaned it up. It is C++ code somewhat modeled after C++ std::list.

https://github.com/jeffareid/misc/blob/master/xorlist.cpp

I did not create a generic template class for this, and instead used unsigned 64 bit integers for the data. It could be converted to a template.

XORNODE - contains an xor link and a unsigned 64 bit integer.

XORITER - "iterator" for the list, contains "previous" and "current" pointers.

XORLIST - xor list class. Contains a dummy node and a pointer to the dummy node used for "end of list", where an "iterator" to that node is equivalent to std::list::end(), and a second pointer to the "first" node (or NULL), where an iterator to the "first" node is equivalent to std::list::begin(), and size (number of nodes). Changing the pointer to the "first" node to a pointer to the "last" node reverses the list in O(1). splice(iterator, other_list) is used to join or splice a second list to a first list in O(1). Other functions: size, front, back, push_front, push_back, pop_front, pop_back, insert, erase, ... .

The sort function is a recursive merge sort where each level of recursion just divides an integer `size` by 2 instead of inefficient scanning of lists to split them. sort() calls the recursive sortr() with a pointer to the "first node" and a size. Recursion just divides size by 2 until the base case size == 1, where it just returns an iterator to next node. The code works with 3 local iterators, `li` is an iterator to start of left run, `ri` is an iterator to end of left run == start of right run, `ei` is an iterator to end of right run. The actual code for sortr() is simple:

```
XORITER sortr(XORITER &li, size_t sz)
{
    XORITER ri;
    XORITER ei;
    if(sz == 1){
        ei = li;
        return ei.next();
    }
    ri = sortr(li, sz-sz/2);
    ei = sortr(ri, sz/2);
    li = merge(li, ri, ei);
    return ei;
}
```

merge() merges two sorted runs, using splice(`li`, `ri)` to move nodes within the list (remove node at `ri`, insert before `li`) as needed (when *`ri` < *`li`).

Answer (score 1):

You can add some logic to your `next()` function so that it would *choose* the neighbor to go to, depending on where you previously came from. The idea is that you should prefer to go to *another* node and not the previous one. Then your algorithm will work.

Note that once you have this logic implemented, it doesn't matter which of the two neighbors you assign to `next` and `prev`. In fact, it might be useful to store these two references in an array of 2, where the order is not important.

Not much related, but I would suggest implementing your doubly linked list as a *circular* list with a sentinel node, so that your linked list is actually a reference to that sentinel node. That sentinal node would also have that array with two node references, but here (as an exception) the order *does* have a meaning: the first entry would reference the head node (if there is one), and the second entry would reference the tail node. The reversal operation then just comes down to reversing that array.

This setup may lead to more elegant code when it comes to inserting and deleting nodes, as you don't have null pointers anymore. For instance, if the list is empty, you still have the sentinel node that will reference itself in two directions.

Here is an implementation of these ideas in a runnable JavaScript snippet. The driver code at the end executes some simple test cases, including the one you describe:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.neighbors = [this, this]; // Self references
    }
    insert(other, side) {
        other.neighbors = [this.neighbors[side], this];
        this.neighbors[side]._replaceNeighbor(this, other);
        this.neighbors[side] = other;
    }
    _replaceNeighbor(find, replace) {
        this.neighbors[this.neighbors.indexOf(find)] = replace;
    }
    getNeighbor(butNot) {
        for (const neighbor of this.neighbors) {
            if (neighbor != butNot) return neighbor;
        }
        throw "neighbor not found";
    }
    clear() {
        this.neighbors[0] = this.neighbors[1] = this;
    }
    remove() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            this.neighbors[i]._replaceNeighbor(this, this.neighbors[i ^ 1]);
        }
        this.clear();
        return this.value;
    }
}

// Circular linked list with an ever present sentinel node
class LinkedList extends Node { 
    constructor(...values) { // Allow to immediately insert values
        super(); // Sentinel node
        for (const value of values) {
            this.pushBack(value);
        }
    }
    isEmpty() {
        return this.neighbors[0] === this;
    }
    pushFront(value) {
        this.insert(new Node(value), 0);
    }
    pushBack(value) {
        this.insert(new Node(value), 1);
    }
    popFront() {
        return this.isEmpty() ? null : this.neighbors[0].remove();
    }
    popBack() {
        return this.isEmpty() ? null : this.neighbors[1].remove();
    }
    reverse() {
        // Swap head and tail references
        this.neighbors.reverse();
    }
    *values() { // Generator
        let i = 0;
        let prev = this, next;
        for (let node = this.neighbors[0]; node !== this; node = next) {
            yield node.value;
            // Get next neighbor (it shouldn't be the back-reference)
            next = node.getNeighbor(prev);
            prev = node;
        }
    }
    concat(other) {
        this.neighbors[1]._replaceNeighbor(this, other.neighbors[0]);
        other.neighbors[0]._replaceNeighbor(other, this.neighbors[1]);
        other.neighbors[1]._replaceNeighbor(other, this);
        this.neighbors[1] = other.neighbors[1];
        other.clear();
    }
}


// Demo
const a = new LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4);
console.log("a:", ...a.values());
const b = new LinkedList(5, 6, 7, 8);
console.log("b:", ...b.values());
b.reverse();
console.log("b (after reversal):", ...b.values());
a.concat(b);
console.log("a (after adding b):", ...a.values());
a.reverse();
console.log("a (after reversal):", ...a.values());
a.pushFront(0);
console.log("a (after prepend ):", ...a.values());
a.pushBack(9);
console.log("a (after append  ):", ...a.values());
a.popFront();
console.log("a (after popFront):", ...a.values());
a.popBack();
console.log("a (after popBack ):", ...a.values());
```